# Phpunit - How do I annotate tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, annotations, phpunit

I'd like to run my tests in separate processes. Because of this, I would like to annotate my tests with "@runTestsInSeparateProcesses". However, I have never annotated Phpunit tests before and I haven't been able to find a good description of where to actually put the annotations. I've seen what the different annotations do, just not where to put them. Could someone please give me an example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotations are applied to your test-case's docblock:

```
/**
 * Short Description
 * 
 * @param string $input The test input
 * 
 * @return bool The result
 * 
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 */
public function test_myMethod ($input) {
  // Test code here
}
```

Read more about DocBlocks: https://docs.phpdoc.org/

Comment: A note about test annotations... If you have enabled PHP's opcache functionality, and the [opcache.save_comments](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.save-comments) configuration option is set to false, then the annotations will not be visible when the test is running.
I recently discovered this when a test listener that I had written to harvest annotations instead returned no annotations.